# Is there any drawback of using transactional on super class?

Tags: spring-boot, transactions

Example case is:

Super-Class:

```
abstract class MySuper {
   @Transactional
   public void handle() {
   }
}
```

Sub-Class:

```
class MySub extends MySuper {

   public void handle() {
      //implement
   }
}
```

I want to add `Transactional` on method level as default behaviour. `handle()` method might be transactional or non-transactional or any db-related action. In this case, is there any drawback for using `Transactional`?

I assume that I can override `Transactional` on method level so when I need readOnly, propagation, rollback options, I can easly handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider some cases one by one:

**First case:** With Transactional no-db operation:

```
@Transactional
public void normalSave() {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    ... some computations.
    Thread.sleep(30000);
}
```

In this case, new redundant connection will be opened on db and it will wait 30 seconds.

**Second case:** With Transactional with-db operation:

```
@Transactional
public void normalSave() {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    testRepository.save(test);
    Thread.sleep(30000);
}
```

In this case, new connection will be opened on db and it will wait 30 seconds to commit it but we have only save method on db-side and most probably it will handle in ms. So redundant.

Note: You can think the `Thread.sleep` operation as some third-party call operations.

And some other pitfalls: https://codete.com/blog/5-common-spring-transactional-pitfalls